# What is the orthogonal part?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, orthogonality, projection

I have heard multiple explanations for what makes something an ORTHOGONAL projection and it's quite confusing.

The first explanation of orthogonal is that if you project b on C(A), the nature of moving the b toward C(A) based on the shortest path is where the orthogonality comes in. But this seems more parallel to me than orthogonal?

The second explanation is that the vector component of b orthogonal to C(A) is the orthogonal part of orthogonal projection. The second explanation makes more sense to me.

But maybe both of those are wrong...

So,
a. Anybody have a good explanation for this?
b. Is the orthogonal complement equal to the vector of residuals? Is it the same thing?

Comment: First explanation: Hold an object (like a ball or a pen) above the floor. What's the shortest path from the object to the floor? What about the shortest path from the object to the wall?

Comment: a. Drop it straight down..so vertical. b. throw it straight across (horizontally)

Comment: Note how it's orthogonal to the floor / wall.

Comment: so how is the b. part related?

Comment: What is $C(A)$? You never define that.

Answer (score 1):

Let $X$ be a finite-dimensional inner-product space over the real or complex numbers, and let $M$ be a subspace of $X$. Let $x\in X$. The orthogonal projection of $x$ onto $M$ is the unique $m\in M$ such that $(x-m)\perp M$. To see why such an $m$ is unique if it exists, suppose that $m,m'\in M$ satisfy $(x-m)\perp M$ and $(x-m')\perp M$; then
$$
              ((x-m')-(x-m))\perp M \\
         \implies (m-m')\perp M \\
         \implies (m-m')\perp (m-m') \\
         \implies m-m'=0 \mbox{ or } m=m'.
$$
So, the orthogonal projection of $x$ onto $M$ is unique if it exists. To find an orthogonal projection of $x$ onto $M$, choose an orthonormal basis $\{ e_n \}_{n=1}^{N}$ of $M$, and verify that the orthogonal projection of $x$ onto $M$ is $m=\sum_{n=1}^{N}\langle x,e_n\rangle e_n$.

Comment: Not familiar with your notation but is x in your example like b in Ax=b? So orthogonal projection of b onto the C(A) (the column space of A) is the unique vector in C(A) such that the result of b - that unique vector (point p which is the approximation of b) is orthogonal to C(A)?

Comment: @ed84 : I have given you the definition of the orthogonal projection of a vector $x$ onto a subspace $M$ of an inner product space. Orthogonal projection and closest-point projection are the same in a finite-dimensional space. Orthogonal projection is defined independent of any other ideas or constructs.

Comment: I've only ever dealt with finite spaces.

Comment: So some of what you are saying is over my head.

Comment: @ed84 : If you think of a subspace $M$ as a plane, then the orthogonal projection of a vector $x$ onto $M$ is the unique $m\in M$ such that $(x-m)\perp M$, which means that $(x-m)\perp m'$ for all $m'\in M$. The orthogonal projection $m$ is unique, and it is also the closest point in $M$ to $x$.